# "stderr;" as a statement throws no warning

Tags: c, gcc, stdout, stderr, gcc-warning

Suppose I have a source code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *p;

int main(void) {
    p;
}
```

... which will compile (using gcc) without any errors or warnings – unless I turn on `-Wall`, in which case a `statement with no effect` warning will be output.

However if the code went like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    stderr;
}
```

... no warnings would be shown regardless of `-Wall`.

Am I missing something here?

*gcc version 9.3.0*

Comment: `stderr` might not be a regular variable, it might actually be macro. Try running your second program through the preprocessor and look what it creates.

Comment: `stderr` is defined as `extern FILE *` but the extern doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Does it also happen with `stdin` and `stdout`?

Comment: @DarkAtom Yes, it does

Comment: `stderr` is required to be defined as a macro. On my implementation (gcc 9.3.0, glibc 2.31) the macro `stderr` expands to `stderr`, and `stderr` is defined as `extern FILE *stderr;`. I see the same behavior. If I `#undef stderr` I do get a warning on `stderr;`. There's probably some special-case code in the compiler. There is no conformance issue, since the standard doesn't require a diagnostic here. I see the same behavior with clang.

Comment: @KeithThompson Do you have any idea how that's related to the standard streams? If I define a macro ```p``` that expands to ```p```, which is declared as ```extern FILE *p```, I will get the same warning.

Comment: It could be related to the fact that the declaration, or the macro definition, comes from a system header.  I seem to recall that gcc handles system headers specially with respect to warnings, on the premise that the user can't do anything about the code therein.

Comment: @NateEldredge That seems to be pretty much it. I've tried it out and it worked just fine. I've added ```extern FILE *p;``` and ```#define p p``` to ```/usr/include/stdio.h```, then proceeded with no warnings

Comment: All the OPs question boils down to is:  when compiling, enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: @user3629249 Not really – your point is inherently valid, but that's not of concern here. Enabling ```-Wall``` (and even ```-Wextra``` in this case) apparently doesn't help a lot when you put ```stderr;``` in your code. One should seek to use ```-Wsystem-headers``` more often (even though that should really not supposed to be necessary here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program:

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *p;
    42;         // statement with no effect
    p;          // statement with no effect
    stderr;     // statement with no effect
    return 0;
}
```

might be expected to elicit 3 `statement with no effect`
diagnostics whenever it elicits any. But as you've discovered,
in the hands of `gcc`, that is not true.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
...

$ gcc -Wall -c main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    6 |     42;
      |     ^~
main.c:7:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    7 |     p;
      |     ^
```

`stderr` - which denotes a `FILE *`, like `p` - has a free pass for being implicitly
evaluated with no effect.

Notoriously, `-Wall` does not *really* enable all warnings. But this free
pass survives to the customary limit of diagnostic rigour:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    6 |     42;
      |     ^~
main.c:7:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    7 |     p;
      |     ^
```

We should be clear that this free pass is carried by the *identfier*
`stderr`, as distinct from the value it names:-

It is not transferable to another `FILE *` by making that other one equal to `stderr`:

```
$ cat main.c; gcc -Wall -c main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *p = stderr;
    42;
    p;
    return 0;
}

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    6 |     42;
      |     ^~
main.c:7:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    7 |     p;
      |     ^
```

It is not enjoyed by the `FILE *` that actually *is* `stderr`, if we do not *refer to it* as `stderr`.

```
$ cat main.c; gcc -Wall -c main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE **p = &stderr;
    42;
    *p;     // a.k.a `stderr`
    return 0;
}

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    6 |     42;
      |     ^~
main.c:7:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    7 |     *p;     // a.k.a `stderr`
      |     ^~
```

But on the other hand, even when `stderr` *is* referred to as `stderr`,
the free pass is forfeit if that identifier is anything less than
the entire context that is evaluated with no effect:

```
$ cat main.c; gcc -Wall -c main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    stdout;             // Undiagnosed
    stderr;             // Undiagnosed
    stderr, stdout;     // Diagnosed once
    42, stderr;         // Diagnosed twice
    stderr - stdout;    // Diagnosed once
    (stderr);           // Diagnosed once
    return 0;
}

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:11: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    7 |     stderr, stdout;     // Diagnosed once
      |           ^
main.c:8:7: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    8 |     42, stderr;         // Diagnosed twice
      |       ^
main.c:8:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    8 |     42, stderr;         // Diagnosed twice
      |     ^~
main.c:9:12: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    9 |     stderr - stdout;    // Diagnosed once
      |            ^
main.c:10:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   10 |     (stderr);           // Diagnosed once
      |     ^
```

Here I've slipped in the assumption that what goes for `stderr` goes likewise
for `stdout`, which is vindicated. It's a notable detail that while `42, stderr;`
is diagnosed as a statement with no effect, `stderr, stdout;` is not.

It seems fair to say that `gcc` does not come across as self-assured about the nature and
limits of the diagnostic immunity it wants to extend to `stderr` and similarly
qualifying identifiers. This is perhaps understandable, when we probe the
ramifications in the sort of code that nobody writes except to fence with the compiler.

Be that as it may, one would like to be clear about the motivation of this diagnostic
immunity and to know whether `gcc` can be told to revoke it, so that, e.g. all of
the ineffectual statements I write in a program will be diagnosed as such.

The answer on the second score is Yes:

```
$ cat main.c; gcc -Wall -Wsystem-headers -c main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *p;
    42;         // statement with no effect
    p;          // statement with no effect
    stderr;     // statement with no effect
    return 0;
}
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    6 |     42;         // statement with no effect
      |     ^~
main.c:7:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    7 |     p;          // statement with no effect
      |     ^
In file included from main.c:1:
main.c:8:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    8 |     stderr;     // statement with no effect
      |     ^~~~~~
```

and:

```
$ cat main.c; gcc -Wall -Wsystem-headers -c main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    stdout;
    stderr;
    stderr, stdout;
    42, stderr;
    stderr - stdout;
    (stderr);
    return 0;
}
In file included from main.c:1:
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:5:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    5 |     stdout;
      |     ^~~~~~
main.c:6:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    6 |     stderr;
      |     ^~~~~~
main.c:7:11: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    7 |     stderr, stdout;
      |           ^
In file included from main.c:1:
main.c:7:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    7 |     stderr, stdout;
      |     ^~~~~~
main.c:8:7: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    8 |     42, stderr;
      |       ^
main.c:8:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    8 |     42, stderr;
      |     ^~
main.c:9:12: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    9 |     stderr - stdout;
      |            ^
main.c:10:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   10 |     (stderr);
      |     ^
```

And the [documentation of `-Wsystem-headers`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)
offers the motivating rationale:

> -Wsystem-headers
>
> Print warning messages for constructs found in system header files. Warnings from
>   system headers are normally suppressed, on the assumption that they usually do not
>   indicate real problems and would only make the compiler output harder to read.
>   Using this command-line option tells GCC to emit warnings from system headers as
>   if they occurred in user code.
>   ...

So, `stderr`, `stderr` get their diagnostic immunity by virtue of being declared in a system
header, `<stdio.h>`<sup>1</sup>. Warnings from system headers are by default assumed to
be spurious.

Before we go about our business, however, its worth appreciating that the documented explanation of
the effect of `-Wsystem-headers`, and of its absence, does not actually explain
those effects as we observe them. The failure to diagnose

```
stderr;     // statement with no effect
```

in our first program in the absence of `-Wsystem-headers` is *not* the suppression
of a warning from a system header. It is the suppression of a warning from `main.c`,
in which that statement is exactly as ineffectual as:

```
p;          // statement with no effect
```

And the effect of `-Wsystem-headers` on the compilation of that program is not
that GCC starts to emit any previously suppressed warning from a system header
*as if it occurred in user code*. It causes GCC to emit a previously suppressed
warning that occurred in user code all along.

Evidently the real effect of the default `-Wno-system-headers` includes, at least,
the suppression of certain warnings, in user code or not, when the context

```
... identifier ...
```

that would otherwise provoke the warning contains an `identifier` that was declared
in a system header. The manual tells us how to stop this, but only gestures
at explaining it.

---

[1] It is not obvious what is meant by *system header* in the documentation,
but experimentation shows that a file is only a *system header* in the
appropriate sense if it is a header file installed by GCC.

Comment: TL;DR: It's a gcc bug. A real one.

Answer (score -1):

Yes... and if you write something like:

```
0;
```

or

```
#include <math.h>
int main()
{

    cos(2.0*M_PI + 7.0);
}
```

you'll get the same result (nothing will happen).  The reason is that a statement can be any expression (of any type) followed by a semicolon `;` in C.  The expression value is just dropped, and execution continues with the next statement (in your case there's none).  In my examples, the 0 value of the expression, or the string literal `"Hello world"` are just dropped by the compiler with a null result.

Comment: The OP' understands why `-Wall` elicits a warning `statement with no effect`
for `p`. They want to know why it does *not* for `stderr`. The right answer is arrived at in the comments.

Comment: Probably the same as for `printf()` which is a function that returns the number of written characters.  Or why if you define a function `printf` gcc considers it as a builtin, when C has never had builtins.

Comment: @LuisColorado ```0;``` will be warned about by using ```-Wall``` as well. Just to clarify what I'm about

Comment: Yeah, but `printf()` won't be warned, and _per se_ it is just a simple expressión that returns the actual number of characters written to far.  So basically, it is equivalent to the expression `0`, or `26`.  The compiler recognises it because as it claims in it's warning messages, it is a **builtin** function (something that `printf` has never been)

Comment: @LuisColorado Doesn't matter whether I discard the output of ```printf()``` or not – it *does* have an effect. Hence no warning

Comment: A warning doesn't mean necessary that the code is incorrect.  The code is correct as shown and I have no disputes with it.  For me the question is opinion searching... and opinion based, and your comment is too. And as such I think the question should be closed.  As stated in K&R 1st edition, `printf()` is not different to other functions and today both `gcc` and `clang'` consider it a builtin function, and so emit warnings related to them specifically.  IMHO this breaks severely the original design spirit.  But what I don'tt want is to come here to discuss.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point right. If I define a function ```int f(void)``` and put a statement ```f();``` into my ```main``` function: no warning whatsoever. The question wasn't opinion searching to begin with. As gcc emits no warnings when using a statement ```stderr;```, I was curious about potential side effects of that statement (just to come here and find out that there are none, fortunately). I'm not saying the code is incorrect; I'm just saying if gcc emits a warning for ```p;``` it should as well emit one for ```stderr;``` – but that's just my opinion, so maybe you're right :)

Comment: The compiler uses a warning in the case of `stderr` because it implies a macro that makes a function call (the new stdio library is thread safe). The compiler doesn't emit any warning because at compilation time it doesn't know if the external function calls of `printf()` or `stderr` will have collateral effects, so it doesn't emit a warning, while something like `0;` or any constant expression would.  But it is not an error.  It could be the result of some programmer's idiom in a macro expansion.  So In my opinion, having all those warnings active only confounds novel programmers, ...

Comment: ... because they tend to thinkg that **any warning** should be eliminated (instead of silenced, or permitted).